# Pass a file through a POST form

Tags: php, file, post

I have a page.php where I load a .csv file, read it and eventually upload the values into a database. What I want to do is, once the file is loaded in my form, and I've read it, first I check into my database if I still have space available, and if there is no space left, I print a message saying there is no space left, do you want to upload it anyway? I can get till this point, but I don't know how to send the file that has already been loaded into my form, to the same page through a post form, or any other method.

Here is how I read the file when I upload it

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

but if I try to send $file variable through a hidden field in the new POST form, it doesn't work.

Comment: Where is the full Code?

Comment: I hope you didnt foget to add `enctype=multipart/form-data` in form tag

Comment: No I haven't, the file loads fine the first time I pick it from my computer, but the second time, when I try to pass it through the hidden value, doesn't work, as I can read here, for security reasons can't be done that way..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send a file through hidden inputs due to security reasons. what I would recommend is to save the uploaded file on server when you read it the first time. Then if user clicks on `anyway`, then pass this saved  file as the input for this 2nd iteration.

Answer (score 0):

It can not repopulate field input.

So you can

1) use ajax to check if there are enough space and show message if no space left

or

2) store data from file in file on web server, and store data about it in hidden field in html form and after second submit use stored file.

Comment: How can I use ajax to check and eventually proceed with the insert? let's say I put the insert query in a function called insert(), how can I do the check with ajax and eventually call that function?

Comment: Advantage of ajax is you need not repopulate form, because you use same html form. Instead of normal submit you send ajax submit with all form data. You ok - you redirect user to another page or reload this page. If error no space left - you show this error and wait user decision.

Comment: problem is I'm not that familiar with ajax, but as far as I can read from your comment, would be the right solution for my issue..

Comment: have you got any link to anything similair, where checking with ajax, and having a message and a button to continue with a query?